# How can I set Foxit as the default plugin for handling PDFs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf-reader, foxit-reader, browser-plugin

I recently installed PDFArchitect, which replaced the Foxit reader plugin in Firefox.

How can I set Foxit's plugin as default for handling in-browser PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **tools>options>applications** to make your changes.

[image: How to change file associations in firefox]

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

1. deactivate the PDFArchitect plugin in Firefox via Add-ons-Manager/Plugins
2. reinstall Foxit

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to disable any other plugin that opens PDF files, then restart Firefox, and open the Tools > Options > Applications window. The Foxit plugin should appear in the dropdown list next to PDF files.